# How to capture ng-model with the ng-bind?

Tags: angularjs, calendar, widget, ng-bind

I'm not able to make the `ng-bind="data1"` capture the input `ng-model="data1"` from the widget. By clicking and choosing a date, `ng-bind` is not capturing the chosen date.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.pt-BR.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Module = angular.module('myapp', []);
    myApp.directive('myapp', function datetimepicker() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                element.datetimepicker({
                        minView: 2,
                        autoclose: true,
                        language: 'pt',
                        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
                        showMeridian: true,
                        startView: 2
                    })
                    .find('input')
                    .addClass("form-control");
            }
        };
    });
</script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myapp">
  <div id="datetimepicker" class="input-append date" ng-model="data1">
     <input ng-model="data1" type="text" datetimepicker></input>
     <p ng-bind="data1">
     <span class="add-on">
        <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
     </span>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not give the same name `myapp` to your module and your directive.

Nowhere in your html you are using the directive.

Also, a `<div>` cannot have a ng-model directive, so this line is wrong:

```
<div id="datetimepicker" class="input-append date" ng-model="data1">
```

Your problem is that you need to initialize `data1` in your controller:

```
function($scope) {
  // Initialization
  $scope.data1 = '';
}
```